# Is a variable like an address in JavaScript and similar to pointer in C

Tags: javascript

Is a variable in JavaScript like an address that points to a location on the hard drive?

I heard of pointers in C but am not sure if it's the same thing in JavaScript.

Comment: Question is too broad for SO.

Comment: If js could access the hard drive directly, there would be  ransomware on every device... There could be sth like a virtual memory js works with, however modern high level languages were invented ( like js ) that no one needs to deal with pointer hell anymore...

Comment: C pointers don't point to a location on the hard drive, so it's difficult to understand what you are trying to ask. However, what is probably relevant is that JavaScript objects/functions are similar to "reference types" in other langugages.

Comment: Once you know the answer to this question, what are you planning to do with your new-found knowledge?

Comment: Do you already *know* C? If not, then don't try to learn JS and C at once.

Comment: Variables are names for locations in memory. That's all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is *usually* an address to a segment of bytes in *RAM*, Random Access Memory or primary memory.

Object variable behave like pointers.

```
var x = {},
     y = x;

y.z = 1;
console.log(x); // {z: 1}
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean by "address to a location".

Comment: "Usually"--when is it not, then?

Comment: Object variables *do* behave similarly to pointers. They're *references* to an underlying object that is only cleared when there are no more references to it.

Comment: @torazaburo It is not in the case of virtual memory, where it could *actually* be on the hard-drive.

Comment: Primitives are passed by value, whereas values in objects are passed by reference, they always point to the same memory location.